# How to test and mock guzzle responses in different situations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, guzzle

I want to test my API controller that using some guzzle requests from another services.
I have one request for making a download link.

1. this is my API route

   ```
   Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1'], function () {
   Route::get('/exampledl', 'DownloadController@downloadChecker');
   });
   ```
2. DownloadChecker controller checks if user is admin or subscriber makes a guzzle request to one of my services on a different domain, if not do another Guzzle request to another service and for each situations responses are different. This is a part of controller checks admin role.

   ```
   $client = new Client();
   try {
       $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/api/user?u=' . $request->uid);
       $json = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), True);

       // if user doesn't exist in CM

       //this part has been written to avoid repeating code
       if (array_key_exists('user', $json) && $json['user'] == null) {
           abort(403);
       }
       elseif (in_array("administrator", $json['Roles'])) {
           User::create([
               'uid'               => (int)$request->uid,
               'subscription.role' => 'administrator',
           ]);
           $client = new Client();
   $response = $client->request('GET', "https://vod.example2.com/vod/2.0/videos/{$a_id}?secure_ip={$u_ip}", [
       'headers' => [
           'authorization' => '**********'
       ]
   ]);
   $json = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), TRUE);

   if (isset($json['data']['mp4_videos'])) {
       $links = [];
       foreach ($json['data']['mp4_videos'] as $mp_video) {
           if (stripos($mp_video, "h_144") !== false) {
               $links['144p'] = $mp_video;
           }
           elseif (stripos($mp_video, "h_240") !== false) {
               $links['240p'] = $mp_video;
           }
           elseif (stripos($mp_video, "h_360") !== false) {
               $links['360p'] = $mp_video;
           }
           elseif (stripos($mp_video, "h_480") !== false) {
               $links['480p'] = $mp_video;
           }
           elseif (stripos($mp_video, "h_720") !== false) {
               $links['720p'] = $mp_video;
           }
           elseif (stripos($mp_video, "h_1080") !== false) {
               $links['1080p'] = $mp_video;
           }
       }
       }
   ```
3. one of my tests.

   ```
   public function test_user_notExist_admin()
   {
   $client = new Client();
   $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.example.com/api/user_days_and_roles?u=' . request()->uid);
   $json = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), True);

   $this->get('/api/v1/exampledl?uid=1&n_id=400&u_ip=104.58.1.45&dl_id=a81498a9')
       ->assertStatus(200)
       ->assertSee('links');

   $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
       'uid'               => (int)request('uid'),
       'subscription.role' => 'administrator',
   ]);
   }
   ```

There are some other conditions check and I'm not sure how to mock these different situations.

Should I make unit test for every situations? Or is there any way to make guzzle in test environment return a custom response? Or any other way?

Comment: Here are a few articles that might point you in the right direction: [How to Mock a Guzzle Request for PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130882/how-to-mock-a-guzzle-request-for-phpunit); [Unit Testing Guzzle inside of Laravel Controller with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162281/unit-testing-guzzle-inside-of-laravel-controller-with-phpunit)

Comment: I could not get the answer from these links. I'm using a newer version of Laravel and PHPUnit from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to mock functions one by one:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(DownloadController::class)->makePartial();
     $mock->shouldReceive('et_download_links_from_download_server')->andReturn('123465');
       $this->app->instance(DownloadController::class,$mock);
```

Comment: It was such a good way for making partial. it seems it doesn't work for static methods.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer.
for mocking a function in different situations it just needs to use  `$mock = \Mockery::mock` and `makePartial();`
like this and it let us to make every return we want without execute the function:

```
public function test_user_notExist_admin()
{
  $mock = \Mockery::mock(DownloadController::class, [
            'get_download_links_from_download_server'       => $this->links,
            'post_details_to_log_server'                    => [200, "new"],
            'connect'                                       => [
                "Roles"         => [
                    "authenticated",
                    "subscriber"
                ]
                , "days" => "38"
            ]
        ]
    )->makePartial();

 $this->get('/api/v1/exampledl?uid=1&n_id=400&u_ip=104.58.1.45&dl_id=a81498a9')
  ->assertStatus(200)
  ->assertSee('links');

  $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
   'uid'               => (int)request('uid'),
   'subscription.role' => 'administrator',
 ]);
}
```

I've created for each API call a method then I mocked them with Mockery in an Array.